# WEBIX Concatenate variable + selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, webix

May I ask if there is other way to call an element in webix because if I use this code

```
  var post_id = 1;
  var comment = $$('#comment'+ post_id.toString()).getValue();
```

it gives me this error

> TypeError: $$(...).getValue is not a function

my element is an text area and I'm already try that in other project it works but my code is like this

```
var comment = $$('#comment').getValue();
```

it gives me the value of my text area. But if I concatenate the selector there's an error. Is there other way to get the element using concatenate? Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `var comment = $$('#comment').getValue() + post_id.toString();`